# Having trouble with converting to upper case within read in file

Tags: java

I am new to Java, so this might be a naive question...

I am trying to work this out, but got stuck after I read in the file and convert to uppercase. Reading in the file and converting to uppercase is successful, but the output generated `'I like water'` twice... how do I carry read in file text to make that upper class without typing String message line?

```java
import java.util.Scanner;   
import java.io.*;           


public class Reading2
{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
   {
      
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
      
      
      System.out.print("Enter the name of a file: ");
      String filename = keyboard.nextLine();

      
      File file = new File(filename);
      Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

      
      String line = inputFile.nextLine();
      
      
      System.out.println("The first line in the file is:");
      System.out.println(line);

      
      String message = "I like water";
      String upper = message.toUpperCase();
      
      System.out.println(message);
      System.out.println(upper);
    }
}
```

Output

```text
Enter the name of a file: pencil.txt
The first line in the file is:
I like water
I like water
I LIKE WATER
```

Comment: If I understood correctly, you want to convert the line from the file to uppercase and print that directly, without initializing a new `String message`?
Also, you can delete the `javascript` tag.

Comment: Remove the lines after `System.out.println(line);` and replace them with `System.out.println(line.toUpperCase());`

Comment: `Files.lines( Path.of( "some_folder" , "some_file.txt" ) ).map( String :: toUppercase ).forEach( System.out :: println) ;`